# Change app root frame in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have two simple questions since I'm very new to Windows Phone programming:

**1:**
How do I cange the `root frame`, or show a different `Page` on startup, in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application? I have a `LoginPage` and then I want to check if the user is logged in show `MainPage` as `root frame` and if the user is not logged in show the `LoginPage`.

**2:**
Windows Phone Silverlight applications seems so different to me compared to the Windows Phone WinRT applications, or maybe I'm just not experienced enough. For example I can't put a placeholder/hint text in a `textBox` in Silverlight but it's super easy in WinRT, why is it like that? Isn't that something very basic that many IDE's implements? Or have I missed something mayor when I'm developing a Silverlight application for Windows Phone?

I know that Windows Phone WinRT is used to create universal apps and Silverlight is used to create only mobile apps for Windows Phone, but why is developing a mobile app in Silverlight so much different (at least to me) compared to build a Windows Phone app i WinRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, use the UriMapper.
The basic principle is that you check if the user is logged in or not and based on that, navigate to the correct view.

The code is not all that complicated, there is a very [good tutorial up on Shawn Kendrot his blog here...](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2012/06/18/Using-a-custom-UriMapper-to-navigate-to-a-login-screen.aspx)

For question 2, how to add some sort of hint/watermark can be done in several different ways.
But a very simple version is presented [on MSDN here...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206995(v=vs.105).aspx) it uses events to set and clear the watermark.

Comment: It's seems a little wierd to have to do this. Both iOS and Android IDE's handle this in a much simpler way. For example by using the articles suggestion you posted with password boxes doesn't work. So hint text in a password box can't be done in Silverlight (?) @Depechie

Comment: Indeed, WP doesn't have everything out of the box... So for passwordbox look at these solutions: http://blog.premchakkungal.com/?p=10 or http://damianblog.com/2011/01/21/wp7-password-watermark/

Comment: The UriMapper worked, but I have a problem I don't understand. When I log in the userIsLoggedInBool is true and when I press the logout button the userIsLoggedInbool is set to false and navigation to the start page is executed correctly. If I log in then restart the app I'm directed to the main page instead of login page and this is correct. But when I then press the logout button the navigation to the start page doesn't work anymore. It is like the navigation on the logout button stops working if the app is resumed and the user is logged in. Am I missing something critical? @Depechie

Comment: Difficult to pin point without some code... if you put a breakpoint in your custom URI mapper can't you see what he is trying to do when the navigation is not working?

Comment: Hm it I think it had to do with that I had the NavigationPage attribute of the DefaultTask element set as my LoginPage. Setting it to a random page in the app seems to have fixed it @Depechie

Answer (score 0):

Point 1
You have to go to `Package.appxmanifest` and under the tab called Application the second field contains the startup page name. Currently it should be `MainPage.xaml`, just change it to `LoginPage.xaml`.

[image]

Point 2
I don't quite understand your question. Silverlight and Windows Runtime are two different platforms, they have in fact many different libraries. The goal of Windows Runtime is to run the same application on several different devices, so different hardware requirements and different resolutions. It was a need to organize the environment differently and of course Microsoft added some minor changes such as the hint text (e.g.).

What is so *different* to you? I did the porting of an app from SL to WinRT but it's not difficult nor tricky at all.

Comment: The app doesn't change the entry point when changing after your suggestion, what can I be missing @fillobotto ?

Comment: After you changed it, save the project and perform a Clean & Re-build